# Redirect output with nmap

Tags: linux, nmap

I have this url `www.southernct.edu`. Using `nmap` how can I redirect the output to the file `nmap.out`

```
nmap www.southernct.edu > nmap.out
```

Would the command above work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try it and see than to ask the question?

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you not have access to `nmap`? Are you asking us to try it for you, and report the results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.

```
[vonedaddy@uscita TEMP]$ nmap www.southernct.edu > nmap.out
[vonedaddy@uscita TEMP]$ cat nmap.out
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-15 20:57 EDT
Nmap scan report for www.southernct.edu (52.87.65.167)
Host is up (0.013s latency).
rDNS record for 52.87.65.167: ec2-52-87-65-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.56 seconds
[vonedaddy@uscita TEMP]$
```